# Nginx refer to the php file if no extension

Tags: nginx, rewrite, url

I simply want to do this:

If the user goes to the address https://example.com/abcd

if the folder "abcd" exists, serve it based on the index file rules.
If not, serve the abcd.php file
If both do not exist, give a 404 error.

Is this possible? If so, how?

Edit: using `try_files $uri.php $uri/ =404;` results in a file download.

Comment: Search for extensionless php for some examples.

Comment: @RichardSmith all of them result in a file download.

Answer (score 1):

Using this worked:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @ext;
}
location ~ \/\.php {
    rewrite "^(.*)\/.php" $1.php last;
}
location ~ \.php$ {
   include /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf;
   fastcgi_pass unix://run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
}
location @ext {
   rewrite "^(.*)$" $1.php;
}
```

[Source](https://www.reddit.com/r/nginx/comments/5e8gxu/nginx_configuration_with_extensionless_php/)